# How to fix the error with popper js and webpack 5 - popper_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

**Problem description** -
I need to use react-recurrence in the project, but when hovering over the days of division the following error appears, I have encountered it before but could not solve, the problem was with the tooltip from the old material UI, is there any way to ignore old versions of material UI or maybe not the problem, if someone knows something about this kind of errors and how to solve them would be very grateful for feedback

**Error**
[image]

**webpack.config.js**

```
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');
const FilterWarningsPlugin = require('webpack-filter-warnings-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const singleSpaDefaults = require('webpack-config-single-spa-react-ts');

module.exports = (webpackConfigEnv, argv) => {
  const defaultConfig = singleSpaDefaults({
    orgName: 'app',
    projectName: 'comm',
    webpackConfigEnv,
    argv,
  });

  return merge(defaultConfig, {
    externals: ['@app/styleguide'],
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.ts', '.d.ts', '.tsx', '.js', '.jsx'],
      preferRelative: true,
      fallback: {
        fs: false,
        tls: false,
        net: false,
        path: false,
        zlib: false,
        http: false,
        https: false,
        stream: false,
        crypto: false,
        'crypto-browserify': require.resolve('crypto-browserify'),
      },
      alias: {
        helpers: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/helpers/'),
        stores: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/stores/'),
        hooks: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/hooks/'),
        components: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
        layouts: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/layouts/'),
      },
      plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: './tsconfig.json' })],
    },
    devServer: {
      port: 8500,
    },
    plugins: [
      new Dotenv({
        path: './.env.development',
      }),
      new FilterWarningsPlugin({
        exclude:
          /There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing/,
      }),
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ],
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    },
  });
};
```